# How to close opened excel file from excel application using python?

Tags: python, excel, file

I want to close excel file using python when excel workbook is open but i am not able to close.

I did tried file.close() but it's throwing error so please can you guys guide what should i do.

Comment: You cannot close a file which is opened in another application. The whole point of the file having locks while it is open is that no other application can mess up what the first one is doing with the file. The only thing you could do is to kill the excel application, but that may corrupt the file which is open.

Comment: Please post your code. Why is the Excel file open to begin with? Why aren't you reading it with Pandas etc. into memory, manipulate it from there?

Comment: @zvone my main purpose is in my excel file two sheets is their one is report sheet and other is raw data so raw data sheet will get new raw data again  again whenever we want to see the report of that data so after updating or changing raw data of the excel file my report sheet should get updated which has excel formula in it directly and when i open that resultant file i want my report should have updated number according to raw data but i don't want formula after calculation so i have done all that process so now i am only struggling to save and close excel file.